# Падает фпс при прокрутке

Tags: html, css

делаю маленький проект в целях учебы, в нем есть две практически идентичные вещи:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(250% 100% at bottom, #eeeeee 50%, #303841 50.1%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  list-style: none;
  background: white;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(33, 33, 33, .3)
}

p {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  outline: none
}

p:first-child {
  width: 40%
}

p:last-child {
  width: 60%
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>123123123</p>
    <p>123123213213</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
var textarea = document.querySelector('.textarea');
textarea.value = 'asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsadsadsadsdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsadsadsadsdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsadsadsadsdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsadsadsadsdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsadsadsadsdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasdsadsadsadsadsdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(250% 100% at bottom, #eeeeee 50%, #303841 50.1%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.pad {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  border-radius: 1rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: #212121;
}

.textarea {
  resize: none;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0 3rem;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class='pad'>
  <div class='panel'></div>
  <textarea class="textarea"></textarea>
  <div class='panel'></div>
</div>
```

но если здесь при прокрутке все работает гладко, то там все начинает жутко тормозить с увеличением ширины окна браузера(чем шире, тем меньше фпс). В чем может быть проблема? Какие свойства могут быть ответственны за это? Анимаций при прокрутке никаких не происходит.

UPD: оказалось во всем виноват градиент у body, добавил в примеры посмотреть. Может кто-нибудь объяснить почему?

Comment: у меня всё четко)

Comment: @meine ну так и у меня все четко в этих демках

Comment: в чем проблема тогда, ничего не пойму

Comment: @meine посмотри ещё раз примеры, я добавил градиент из за которого у меня тормозит, у тебя так же или это у меня никчемный капуктер?

Comment: у меня всё хорошо, ничего не тормозит

Comment: @meine ты на полный экран открывал?

Comment: да, на полный экран

Comment: да не за что, желаю успехов!